# undefined method user_path' form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a UsersController and it has below code

```
def sign_up
@user = User.new
end
```

And my view page has

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :first_name%>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
      <%= f.label :last_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
      <%= f.submit "Register", class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

My routes.rb file contains the following entry

```
 get 'signup' => 'users#sign_up'
```

But When I submit the form, it says

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000004d91490>:0x00000004d90220>)
```

Why does this throw an error and do I need to explicity point to url in the form_for?? Why is it so??

Comment: add `resources :users` to routes.rb

Comment: @test But since this is only for user registration, I dont need those 7 methods for CRUD operations. I dont know whether I am doing the right way. But I just defined a signup method and inside that I am sending mail to users after sign up

Comment: do you have actions (like create and update action) on your controller and them path on routes?

Comment: @anonymousxxx No. I dont have those. BTW I dont need update action as of now since the user will sign up and an registration mail will be sent.

Comment: It (update action) just example, if you don't have, you need make one action for post registration like create action,

Comment: if you need signup for name of path, try this `resources :users, only: [:new, :create], :path => "/", :path_names => { :new => "sign_up" }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your routes to:

```
resources :users, only: [:new, :create], path_names: {new: 'sign_up'}
```

and rename your `sign_up` action back to `new`. The reason you are getting the error is rails trying to guess the correct url for given resource. Since you have passed `@user`, which is an instance of `User` class, it will try to call `"#{@user.class.model_name.route_key}_path` key, which results in the error you got.

To solve the issue you need either make your routes to define `users_path` or you need to specify the url directly using `url` option. `users_path` can be defined by either `index` or `create` action, so the above solution will work (and will not create remaining CRUD routes, yey!)

Comment: I renamed the sign_up method to new. and did the resources :users, only: [:new, :create], path_names: [new: 'sign_up'] correctly in routes.rb. Removed get 'signup' => 'users#sign_up'. But it still shows error as "`override_keys': undefined method `key?' for [{:new=>"signup"}]:Array (NoMethodError)"

Comment: @rubyist - Ah, my bad, wrong brackets. Will fix in sec.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this line:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

to this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: 'signup') do |f| %>
```